# compare previous value using forEach

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to compare previous using a forEach? I need to calculate how many slot is needed but my data is put into a array of object. The restriction is that I can't sum them first.

```js
const arr = [{
    school: 'us',
    val: 3
}, {
    school: 'uk',
    val: 4
}, {
   school: 'china',
   val: 2
}]

slot = 0
arr.forEach(v => {
    //each slot can fit max 3 us && 3 uk && 3 china
})

console.log(slot) //expected 2
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer updated my question, it's like this `For 3 us, 4 uk and 2 china can be fit in 2 slots.
`

Comment: *Why* is the expected value 2?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```js
arr.forEach(v => {
    //each slot can fit max 3 us && 3 uk && 3 china
    while (v.val > 3*slot) {
       slot++;
    }
})
```